# BitmapMetadata.GetQuery() threw "Metadata query request is not valid"

Tags: c#, metadata, tiff, decoder

I am trying to extract time information from a tiff file using metadata class; Here is the part where time information is in the tiff file:

```
<Plane TheZ="0" TheT="0" TheC="0" DeltaT="0.2345"/>
```

where  0.2345 is the information I am trying to extract.
And here is my code that tried to get it out:

```
string searchtext = "DeltaT=";
FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            TiffBitmapDecoder tbd = new TiffBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);

            if (tbd.Frames[0] != null && tbd.Frames[0].Metadata != null)
            {
                //BitmapMetadata bmd = new BitmapMetadata("tiff");

                BitmapMetadata bmd = tbd.Frames[0].Metadata as BitmapMetadata;

                bmd.GetQuery(@searchText);              

            }
```

However, the line `bmd.GetQuery(@searchText)`;  threw an exception `"Metadata query request is not valid"`; I am not sure how to change it to make it get the 0.2345 value. Anyone has any idea? Thanks alot.

Here is the tiff file so that you can take a look: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/105139407/ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0003.tif

Comment: Could you upload the TIFF file so we can have a look?

Comment: Of course. Here it is: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/105139407/ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0003.tif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the XML you're looking for is in "/ifd/{ushort=270}" (don't ask me why - I don't know anything about how TIFF metadata is supposed to look like...). Note that it returns the whole XML document, so you still have to parse it. This code retrieves the value of `DeltaT`:

```
var decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(new Uri(fileName), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
var metadata = (BitmapMetadata)decoder.Frames[0].Metadata;
string xml = (string)metadata.GetQuery("/ifd/{ushort=270}");
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var plane = doc.Root.Element(ns + "Image")
                    .Element(ns + "Pixels")
                    .Element(ns + "Plane");
double deltaT = (double)plane.Attribute("DeltaT");
```

EDIT: here's a LINQPad script I use to have a quick look at the metadata of an image: http://pastebin.com/daBTdW33. Feel free to use it or adapt it to your needs ;)

Comment: Terrific, although it says System.Windows.Xml.Linq.XDocument does not contain method Dump(); I am using System.Linq, System.Xml, and I have added System.Xml.Linq; Something else I should be using perhaps?

Comment: @NickTsui, the".Dump()" was just something I forgot to remove... It's an extension method available in LINQPad to print the value of a variable.

Comment: I see. So should I do some change to make Dump() work? Something like adding a using, namespace....something like that? Sounds like I don't really need it? Thanks.

Comment: @NickTsui, no, you can just remove that statement (I edited the code to remove it).

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thanks a lot, it totally works. I think I need to read more of it to understand it. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719904(v=vs.85).aspx#_tiff_metadata contains additional data about metadata queries.